# How to cancel ongoing HTTP requests when there's a new requests in angular 6 with rxjs 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm having below `RxnsSearchService` and `RxnsSearchHitCountService`, two HTTP services in my app.

handling two requests with `forkJoin`like below code.

```js
constructor(
  private rxnsSearchService: RxnsSearchService,
  private rxnsSearchHitCountService: RxnsSearchHitCountService
) { }
const rxnsObservable: Observable<Array<any>> = this.rxnsSearchService.getReactions(this.searchParams, filters);
const headCountObservable: Observable<number> = this.rxnsSearchHitCountService.getHitCount(this.searchParams, filters);
forkJoin([rxnsObservable, headCountObservable]).pipe().subscribe((results) => { //handling results 
},
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I want to cancel the ongoing old requests whenever there is a new request comes. can anyone help me, to make it work around?

```js
export class RxnsSearchService {
  sub: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getReactions(params: Params, offset: number, perPage: number, filters: any) {
    const body = {
      filters: filters,
      query: params.query
    };
     return this.httpClient.post(environment.rxnsSearch, body).pipe(
      map((response: Array<any>) => {
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```js
export class RxnsSearchHitCountService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getHitCount(params: Params, filters: any) {
    const body = {
      filters: filters,
      query: params.query,
    };
    return this.httpClient.post(environment.rxnsSearchHitCount, body).pipe(
      map((response: number) => {
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is actually calling forkJoin ? From your code snippet it looks like forkJoin is only ever called once. Can you provide additional code that shows what triggers the forkJoin? Thanks!

Comment: `this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
      this.displayreactions();
    }
  });
}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (!changes['filters'].isFirstChange()) {
    this.displayreactions();
  }
}`

Comment: `forkJoin` called from multiple methods.

Comment: [GitHub link](https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/search/blob/master/src/app/rxn-search/components/rxn-results/rxn-results.component.ts) LineNo:123

Answer (score 12):

I'll go through the general approach of how to do it, with a simplified example. Say we currently have this:

```
public getReactions() {
  this.http.get(…)
    .subscribe(reactions => this.reactions = reactions);
}
```

The way to ensure that old requests are cancelled is by instead emitting on some subject:

```
private reactionsTrigger$ = new Subject<void>();

public getReactions() {
  this.reactionsTrigger$.next();
}
```

Now we have an observable representing the stream of events triggering a new request. You can now implement `OnInit` to something like this:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.reactionsTrigger$.pipe(
    // Use this line if you want to load reactions once initially
    // Otherwise, just remove it
    startWith(undefined),

    // We switchMap the trigger stream to the request
    // Due to how switchMap works, if a previous request is still
    // running, it will be cancelled.
    switchMap(() => this.http.get(…)),

    // We have to remember to ensure that we'll unsubscribe from
    // this when the component is destroyed
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  ).subscribe(reactions => this.reactions = reactions);
}

// Just in case you're unfamiliar with it, this is how you create
// an observable for when the component is destroyed. This helps
// us to unsubscribe properly in the code above
private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
public ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

---

The line

```
    switchMap(() => this.http.get(…)),
```

in your case might actually switch the events to the `forkJoin`:

```
    switchMap(() => forkJoin([rxnsObservable, headCountObservable])),
```

if you want a single event stream to trigger both requests anew.

Comment: This is actually a better and more complete explanation. I would include the forkJoin() statement in your switchMap operator, so that it better fits the asked question, then this could be the accepted answer

Comment: @ggradnig Thanks, I've updated my answer to add this as well.

Comment: @IngoBürk as you took the role to explain the general approach, it would be great for newbies in rxjs like me to make it complete. I mean to combine `switchMap` with `debounce` to cut out fast typing artefacts and minimize the number of canceled requests. the solution could be: `switchMap(val => timer(500).pipe(switchMap(() => this.getResults(val))))` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290603/switchmap-and-debouncetime-cancel-pending/62543975#62543975)

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful to see a code snippet that shows the actual **trigger** of the HTTP requests, but it's most likely a UI component that calls a function on click.

The way you would solve this with RxJS 6 is by using a `Subject` for receiving the click events and then using the `switchMap` operator to cancel unfinished requests in order to prevent backpressure. Here is an example:

```
private clickSubject$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

constructor() {
    this.clickSubject$
        .pipe(switchMap(() => forkJoin([rxnsObservable, headCountObservable])))
        .subscribe((results) => // handling)
}

onClick() {
    this.clickSubject$.next(undefined);
}
```

If you have multiple places where you want to execute the http request, then emit into the subject with: `this.clickSubject$.next(undefined)`;

Comment: Thankyou @ggradnig, it seems this will be helpful, will make the changes.

Comment: @ggrading I have pushed code [GitHub](https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/search/blob/master/src/app/rxn-search/components/rxn-results/rxn-results.component.ts)

Comment: `forkJoin` in the `displayreactions` method lineNo:123

Comment: Thank you very much @ggrading, You really saved lot of my time.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the debounce operator in RxJs:

```
debounce(1000);
```

its a method provided in to set a delay in milliseconds before sending any request,

The example replaces all the requests fired in 1000ms with only one request.

For further detail:

```
fromEvent(input, 'input').pipe(
       map((e: any) => e.target.value),
       debounceTime(500),
       distinctUntilChanged()
     ).subscribe(
       (data) => {
           this.onFilterTable({column: fieldName, data});
       }
     );
```

Comment: sometimes my results are taking a little longer than expected meanwhile user changing his opinion (filtering options), that's why I want to cancel the requests and make new requests.

Comment: can you help to get by using `switchmap`?

Comment: I'm having  lot of checkboxes as well, in that even if I make it by `debounceTime`. If the user changes after one sec, it's messing with old and new results.

Comment: I intention was cancel the old request whenever the new request comes.

Comment: debounceTime should go first in chain, there's no need for mapping first