# switchMap and debounceTime cancel pending

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a method that will search for employee's based on a search term.

```
this._sub.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    filter(x => !!x),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(this.getResults.bind(this))
).subscribe((d: IDisplayEmp[]) => {
    console.log('RES', d)
    this.displayResults = d;
});

this._sub.next('mySearchTerm');
```

This works great, previous API calls are cancelled if a new one is issued. However here comes the issue.

Active API calls are only cancelled when the debounce has emitted. If an active API call returns whilst the debounce is waiting it still triggers my subscribe.

I understand this is because the cancelling only happens within the scope of the switchmap.

Is possible to refactor this so that if the debounce is waiting for input to stop it will cancel any pending API calls?

Probably a naive approach but i attempted something like below, it emits values but now there is no debounce in effect.

```
this._sub.pipe(
    filter(x => !!x),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((x) => {
        return of(x)
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                this.getResults.bind(this)
            );
    })
).subscribe((d: IDisplayEmp[]) => {
    console.log('RES', d)
    this.displayResults = d;
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you want to achieve. Maybe `throttleTime` does what you want?

Comment: @martin I'm attempting to debounce input then make an API call. Should new input come in the debounce will wait for input to stop before emitting the resulting value. I would like the active API call (if there is one) to be cancelled when the debounce is waiting, not after it has emitted which is current behaviour. Thanks for the info ill look into `throttleTime`

Comment: Then you should `concat` your api calls. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Comment: @ritaj Sorry i'm struggling to see how to apply that, im only triggering a single API call when the debounce emits a value?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: @ste2425 From what you describe it looks like you don't want to be using `debounceTime` at all. `switchMap` will unsubscribe from the previous calls for you. Maybe `throttleTime` with the config object is really what you want. Otherwise if you could make marble diagram of what output you expect that would be very helpful.

Comment: @martin i have seen marble diagrams in the docs and they have confused me no end. Been putting of learning how on earth to read them, guess i need to get on with it thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `takeUntil` to cancel your requests whenever `this._sub` emits.

```
this._sub.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    filter(x => !!x),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(searchTerm => this.getResults(searchTerm).pipe(
      takeUntil(this._sub)
    ))
).subscribe((d: IDisplayEmp[]) => {
    console.log('RES', d)
    this.displayResults = d;
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great! Looking at the docs and your comment it makes sense too.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer should work fine, but I wanted to share another way you can do this with `timer` instead of `debounceTime`:

```js
this._sub.pipe(
    filter(x => !!x),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(val => timer(500).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.getResults(val))
    ))
).subscribe(...);
```

Now, if an emissions reaches `switchMap`, the `timer` and everything in it (including an active network request) will be canceled, and a new `timer` will be created.

Comment: This is actually one line shorter than using `takeUntil` as well, since you don't have to use `debounceTime` and both require an inner pipe inside your `switchMap`.

Comment: this one must be the accepted answer in general case! say I don't have a subject variable, but use one-liner `this.myCustomCombobox.filterChange.asObservable()`, then I can't use `takeUntil` (or have to introduce a variable), but the `timer` solution still works!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work for you:

Use `concat` so the second emission waits for the first one to complete.

```
const getFromAPI = (key: string): Observable<number> => {
    return;
};

const keys: Observable<string> = new Observable();

concat(
    keys.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(key => getFromAPI(key)),
        take(1)
    )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Another example:

```
const getFromAPI = (key: string): Observable<number> => {
    return;
};

const keys: Observable<string> = new Observable();

const debouncedKeys = keys.pipe(debounceTime(500));

concat(
    debouncedKeys.pipe(
        switchMap(key => getFromAPI(key)),
        take(1),
        takeUntil(debouncedKeys)
    )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Ahh i understand now, thanks for going to the effort of an example. However this isn't the behaviour im after. `keys` will be the search terms a user entered in a input. I need it to cancel a previous pending request whenever a new search term is emitted, but only issue a new API after a debounced period of time. I think that is a better explanation, ill update the OP!

Comment: Oh, I believe you just want to add `takeUntil` then. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure here, need to be explored, but you could transform the _sub into two observables, one will be debounced and returns the original query, the second is not debounced and returned null/undefined.

Then you merge them both and call the switchMap.

The undebounced observable should allow you to cancel the call because it will reach the switchmap too. In with case the switchMap could return an empty or never observable. And you recreate the API call only when it's the debounched observable that came in with the value.

Something like that?

```
const debounced = this._sub.pipe(debounceTime(500), filter(x => !!x), distinctUntilChanged());
const undebounced = this._sub.pipe(map(_ => undefined));

merge(debounced, undebounced).pipe(
    switchMap(val => {
        if (val) {
            return this.getResults(val);
        } else {
            return never;
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, however the accepted answer solved my problem.